# Does putExtra() method of class Intent return a value of Intent object?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am a new newbie learning Android development following the tutorial on `developer.android.com`.
The `putExtra()` method of class Intent returns a value of Intent object. But the code of the tutorial is `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);`. If so, the method can not return a value.
Can you tell me why? Thank you very much.

Comment: it put the extra to the next activity/service/etc then with getStringExtra (etc, depend on what you want to get; in this case a string) you read it

Comment: intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message) will return the instance of the Intent you're adding it to. This would allow you to do things like: new Intent().putExtra("variable_1", variabl1).putExtra("variable_2", variable2) inline

Comment: intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message) means the method is a void method. I can not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The put extra data can be accessed in the following activity using getIntent.getextras in to a bundle object. The bundle object then can be used to return the data using getString using the EXTRA MESSAGE as a key.